# HIVE CTE with UNION ALL is throwing table not found exception

Tags: hive

My intension is to load the table only once with `CTE` and reuse the `CTE` table, to avoid multiple table loading and stages in Hive.
But the below hive query is running through hue and throwing `table cases not found` exception when running through cloudera 5.11 version.
Any error in the query usage?

```
WITH cases
AS (
    SELECT nbr
        ,id
        ,date_l2
        ,date_l3
        ,date_l4
        ,date_l5
        ,level_2
        ,level_3
        ,level_4
        ,level_5
    FROM volume
    )
SELECT nbr
    ,id
    ,CONCAT (
        nbr
        ,'-L2'
        ) AS enbr
    ,'L2' AS level_nm
    ,date_l2 AS dt
FROM cases
WHERE level_2 = true

UNION ALL

SELECT nbr
    ,id
    ,CONCAT (
        nbr
        ,'-L3'
        ) AS enbr
    ,'L3' AS level_nm
    ,date_l3 AS dt
FROM cases
WHERE level_3 = true

UNION ALL

SELECT nbr
    ,id
    ,CONCAT (
        nbr
        ,'-L4'
        ) AS enbr
    ,'L4' AS level_nm
    ,date_l4 AS dt
FROM cases
WHERE level_4 = true

UNION ALL

SELECT nbr
    ,id
    ,CONCAT (
        nbr
        ,'-L5'
        ) AS enbr
    ,'L5' AS level_nm
    ,date_l5 AS dt
FROM cases
WHERE level_5 = true
```

Output:
nbr         id          enbr        level_nm     dt
00193092    84575   00193092-L2         L2      2016-10-19
00193092    84575   00193092-L3         L3      2016-10-20
00193092    84575   00193092-L4         L4      2016-10-20

Comment: Consider using proper formatting in the body of the question, and providing a minimal working example.

Comment: Not sure about your error, but the CTE is still going to be executed for each select it's referred to in.  It doesn't behave the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  t.nbr
       ,t.id
       ,concat(t.nbr,'-L',s.nm) as enbr
       ,concat('L',s.nm)        as level_nm
       ,s.dt

from    volume  t
        lateral view stack 
        (
            4
           ,'2',t.level_2,t.date_l2
           ,'3',t.level_3,t.date_l3
           ,'4',t.level_4,t.date_l4
           ,'5',t.level_5,t.date_l5
        ) s as nm,lvl,dt

where   s.lvl = true
;
```

Comment: Some explanation of what this is doing would be helpful.

Comment: @Andrew, as soon as the OP will supply a sample data.

Comment: Thanks Dudu Markovitz. It worked.
Below is the sample output.

nbr     id   enbr  level_nm  dt
00193092 84575 00193092-L2   L2  2016-10-19
00193092 84575 00193092-L3   L3  2016-10-20
00193092 84575 00193092-L4   L4  2016-10-20

Comment: Please add it to the original post